# How to delay squiggly lines (error warnings) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, code-completion

When writing code, red lines appear over the code that has just been written untill I complete the line

Eg: "System.Ou"

Will generate an error until the line gets completed.

This functionality is obviously good, however the fact that the error messages pop up while I'm typing is very distracting. Is there any way to delay the error lines showing up? Even 5 seconds after I begin writing my line would give me time to finish what I had originally planned to write.

Comment: What do you mean by error messages `pop up`?  Something steals the focus while you're typing?

Comment: The focus remains the same, but the 'error lines' trail what you are writing until you finish the line. It is really a visual distraction.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a bit old, but I believe I found the answer to your question [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/disable-squiggly-or-wavy-lines-in.html).

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced and under the "Editor Help" section uncheck "Show live semantic errors."